# Use ngx-bootstrap/typeahead to search for files from a list of predetermined directories

Tags: angular, rxjs, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [ngx-typeahead](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead#async-http-request) to search for files ,asynchronously, on my network from a list of predetermined directories. If no files are found in the 1st directory ,matching the search pattern, the next directory should be searched and so on until all directories have been searched or files matching the pattern are returned. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

```
 public dwgs: Observable<any>;
  searchableDirs = [
    'm:\\592000\\',
    'm:\\582500\\',
    'm:\\582300\\'
  ]
constructor() {
    this.dwgs = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    let globPattern = `${this.searchableDirs[0]}${this.dwg}*.+(dwg|DWG)`
      observer.next(globPattern);
    })
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((token: string) => this.globService.getDwgs2(token))
        )
  }
```

If I type a file in the first dir I get results but if the file is located in the 3rd dir(582300) I get nothing of course.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. I am using expand to recursively do a query quitting when data is returned or there are no more directories to search.If anyone has a better way let us know.

```
public dwgs: Observable<any>;
  searchableDirs = [
    'm:\\592000\\',
    'm:\\582500\\',
    'm:\\582300\\'
  ]
constructor() {
    this.dwgs = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
      //start at top of array ex:592000
      currentDir = this.searchableDirs[0];
      //build pattern
      let globPattern = `${currentDir}${this.dwg}*.+(dwg|DWG)`
      observer.next(globPattern);
    })
      .pipe(
        //make request
        mergeMap((token: string) => this.globService.getDwgs2(token)
        .pipe
        (
          expand((data: any) => {
            // find index of currentDir in array
            let nextDirIndx = this.searchableDirs.indexOf(currentDir)
            // increment by 1 for next dir in array 
            nextDirIndx = nextDirIndx+ 1;
            // if the next index is more than dirs in array return EMPTY to quit
            if(nextDirIndx > this.searchableDirs.length -1) return EMPTY;
            // otherwise set currentDir to next dir
            currentDir = this.searchableDirs[nextDirIndx];
            //build pattern
            let globPattern = `${currentDir}${this.dwg}*.+(dwg|DWG)`;
            return isEmpty(data)
             // if data is empty use new dir in pattern
              ? this.globService.getDwgs2(globPattern)
               // otherwise return EMPTY to quit
              : EMPTY;
          })
        ))
        )
  }
```